# gnome login fail after a upgrade: oh no something has gone wrong

Tags: kali-linux, gnome3, gnome-shell

I upgraded my Kali Linux version 2 and now when I try to login in my Desktop I got this error message "oh no something has gone wrong".

I go to the console mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and I launch `gnome-shell` and it return this:

```
(gnome-shell:4934): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to open display. You have to set the DISPLAY environment variable, or use the --display command line argument
(gnome-shell:4934): mutter-ERROR **: Unable to initialize Clutter.
```

I check `/var/log/messages` and I found:

```
Jan 13 18:48:05 kali kernel: [  106.005592] traps: gnome-shell[3992] trap int3 ip:7f159197ad30 sp:7ffe8c719c80 error:0
```

`dmesg` return the same message.

I installed `X-window-system` and `xorg` after a `apt-get update`.

I added a user and I try to login with this but it doesn't work.

`journalctl` returns `No journal files were found`.

My CPU is a `i5-3210M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is python. I get a error with a package when I do `apt-get upgrade`.

It's because the `usr/bin/python` link to python3.4. So I change this for python2.7 and I do again `apt-get upgrade` and this solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is an upgrade bug, I had faced this issue too.

Here's a quick fix though, till the Offsec guys fix it.
Spawn a tty. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>

> nano /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf

Uncomment the first two lines that enable auto login for the root user.

```
AutomaticEnableLogin = true
AutomaticLogin = root
```

This is probably not the best fix from a security perspective so you can also add a non root user and enable it to auto login.

```
AutomaticEnableLogin = true
AutomaticLogin = <username>
```

In case you need to add a user,

> useradd -m username -G sudo -s /bin/bash
>
> passwd username

Comment: automatic login doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

After the log out screen appears, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then restart the update and full upgrade. It can be because of interruption while unpacking the packages and libraries. Enter the command

```
sudo apt-get update && apt -y full-upgrade
```

and it will install and unpack the new packages and after that run

```
[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot -f
```

Hope this will help.